# How to convert numbers to words in odoo?

Tags: python, odoo, openerp-7

In the invoice, I want to convert total amount to words in Indian numbering system(hundreds, thousands, lakhs, crores). I cant use amount_to_text library module since it has been set in euro currency. So how to write function in python to achieve this? (dont worry abt indendation,its correct in my system) When i tried this code in my custom module, i get this error 
TypeError: _int2word() takes exactly 1 argument (7 given)

```
class account_invoice(models.Model):
_inherit = "account.invoice"
print "hello"

ones = ["", "one ","two ","three ","four ", "five ", "six ","seven ","eight ","nine "]
tens = ["ten ","eleven ","twelve ","thirteen ", "fourteen ","fifteen ","sixteen ","seventeen ","eighteen ","nineteen "]
twenties = ["","","twenty ","thirty ","forty ","fifty ","sixty ","seventy ","eighty ","ninety "]
thousands = ["","thousand ","lakh ", "crore "]

def _int2word(amount_total):

    n = amount_total
    n3 = []
    r1 = ""
    ns = str(n)
    for k in range(3, 33, 3):
        r = ns[-k:]
        q = len(ns) - k

        if q < -2:
            break
        else:
            if  q >= 0:
                n3.append(int(r[:3]))
            elif q >= -1:
                n3.append(int(r[:2]))
            elif q >= -2:
                n3.append(int(r[:1]))
        r1 = r

    nw = ""
    for i, x in enumerate(n3):
        b1 = x % 10
        b2 = (x % 100)//10
        b3 = (x % 1000)//100
        #print b1, b2, b3  # test
        if x == 0:
            continue  # skip
        else:
            t = thousands[i]
        if b2 == 0:
            nw = ones[b1] + t + nw
        elif b2 == 1:
            nw = tens[b1] + t + nw
        elif b2 > 1:
            nw = twenties[b2] + ones[b1] + t + nw
        if b3 > 0:
            nw = ones[b3] + "hundred " + nw
    return nw

_columns = {
    'amount_words': fields.function(_int2word, string='In Words', type="char"),
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `amount_to_text_en` function from `openerp.tools` this function takes 3 parameters the_value , the_partner.lang and the currency_name then it will be not just Euro it will return any currency you pass to it.

Comment: is this how should i pass, amount_to_text(amount_total,en,inr)

Comment: yep where inr is the currency_name :)

Comment: It didn't work, but after modifying the original source code of amount_to_text its working now

Comment: hello Bhanukiran, have you got the solution for your problem of amount_to_text in indian words ? Also can you let me know what you had to modify ?

Comment: @MostafaMohamed, dear I'm trying to apply this feature in Odoo 13, but unfortunately, I got `ImportError: cannot import name 'amount_to_text_en' ` error upon updating the module containing the import and code. Do you have any idea about the changes in this feature in Odoo 13?