# How to print amount_to_text in Indian Rupees format in Odoo reports.?

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8

I was trying to print the invoice amount in words in Odoo,

Following is the code in .py

```
@api.multi
    def amount_to_text(self, amount_total, currency='INR'):
        return amount_to_text(amount_total, currency)
```

and following was the code in qweb report,

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-10">
                    <strong><td>Total in words:</td></strong>
                      <span t-esc="o.amount_to_text(o.amount_total, 
'INR')"/>

            </div>
</div>
```

but the report always shows the words in euros(as in the below image), not able to print it in INR format. Is there any over-riding of amount_to_text method.

[image: Amount in Euro words]

Comment: Anyone with any suggestions on this, Please guide me on this, really would be a great help ..!!

Comment: you can try this [How to convert numbers to words in odoo?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33582154/how-to-convert-numbers-to-words-in-odoo)

Answer (score 1):

First of all go to Settings -> Reports -> Reports and search for `invoices` in order to find the Invoice report that interests you. Open it, and uncheck `Reload from attachment`.

If `Reload from attachment` is checked only the first time the report will be generated for a record and it will be saved in the database. If you try to re-print the report (for the same record), Odoo will fetch the saved one and will not re-render a new one.

Also, I checked the definition of this method of Odoo and it does not match your definition.

On `openerp/tools/amount_to_text.py` around line 170 you will find the definition of this method. You can see that it is a static method that is offered as a tool so the proper way to use this method would be:

`from openerp.tools.amount_to_text import amount_to_text`

Now you can call the method with the relevant arguments. The method is sufficiently documented and you can figure out easily how it is used.

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for your valuable answer George, but by default amount_to_text has currency of euros, french or dutch and it prints the report in euros. As far as I saw amount_to_text for Indian Rupee currency does not convert the amount to text in INR format, Hence it does not show in INR currency unit words

Comment: George D, any suggestion on how to proceed ?